Отключение Иерархии прав доступа в Windows
Я почему-то не могу управлять отдельными галочками разрешения и запрета. Когда хочу выбрать запретить изменение то он сразу все галочки запрещает вплоть до изменения хотя мне нужно только одну или две запретить. я попробовал в разделе дополнительно убрать наследование но всё равно не вышло, тогда попробовал также в разделе: дополнительно/User/изменить. Там поставить галочки но там такая же фигня. Я знаю что вся эта проблема и за иерархией прав доступа винды или права доступа для папок и файлов могут быть наследуемыми или типа того, но немого это отключить. Я плохо объясняю, поэтому надеюсь из картинок все понятно станет.
[
[


